# Mysql query to show value that matches exact values only

Tags: mysql

I have a table table1 in mysql containing a column named data_id `INT (11)`.The table contains a record having data_id = 7.But when I execute the query 
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE data_id='7Îüï´Ü'` , 
it returns row having data_id=7. But I want the query to show results only when exactly '7' as the data_id value is supplied, i.e.,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE data_id='7'
```

How this can be done?

Comment: MySQL never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of is checking the input value with an additional regex

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE data_id = $value
AND $value regexp '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: Assuming OP is using PHP?

Comment: No. Just giving an example of an input value.

Comment: Is it a bug in Mysql ?

Comment: No, MySQL automatically tries to compare the 2 values and casts your input to an `int` to make the compare to your `int` column. Doing that it throughs away the characters after the digits. Probably would be better to validate your input before and allow only numbers.